# C# WindowsForm: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, validation, helper

Newbie here, whenever I dont input/input letter then click next button I get this error[System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' ] I dont know what to do. I just follow the instruction[image][image]

Im expecting whenever I clicked Nextbutton, I dont get that error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 1) [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612) 2) The error means that the value in the TextBox cannot be converted to an `int`. Consider using `int.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to cast string to int. Error msg: Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339599/not-able-to-cast-string-to-int-error-msg-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-for)

Comment: If you don't enter anything in the textbox, that mean it is an empty string. Empty string can not be converted to a number, that's why you are getting this error. If you don't expect and empty string then you should put a check `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStudentNo.Text))` before converting it to a number.